# Watir not finding all elements with a class name

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

I'm trying to find all span elements which have a class in a "feed" website with Watir.

The site loads more posts as I get to the bottom. 
I'm currently using the following code:

```
# Go to the bottom of the page
browser.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
likes = @browser.elements(:xpath, "//*[contains(@class, 'className')]")
# I also tried with the following
likes = @browser.spans(:class => "className")
```

The element I'm searching follows the following style:

```
<span class="random_value className ">Like</span>
```

But when I'm doing a `likes.length` I got fewer elements (3) or none when there are, at least, 25 spans with the class `className`.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce the issue? Or provide the URL for the site-under-test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
likes = @browser.spans(:class => "className")
```

This one clearly wouldn't work because you are speaking like class name contains "className" so you better write with regular expression

```
likes = @browser.spans(:class => /className/)
```

Or go with your other option with a little correction since you only want span, you don't have to use * instead use `span`

```
likes = @browser.elements(:xpath, "//span[contains(@class, 'className')]")
```

Watir usually wait until page loads completely when you are navigating one page to another, we don't have to use any static sleep statement but Since you say page loads more span when get to the bottom your case seems to be little different ,I strongly suspect the above code executes quickly even before page loads completely so put `sleep 5` to check whether you get increase in number of spans, so write the following code with  `sleep 5`

WATIR has the `execute_script` for you, so you don't have to use selenium `execute_script` directly

```
@browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 5
likes = @browser.elements(:xpath, "//span[contains(@class, 'className')]")
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. I found that the reason for Watir not finding all the divs was that when I go to the bottom of the page, React unloads the other span, so, by searching for the current spans, interacting, and then going to the bottom, I'm having the desired functionality.